# How to provide servlets from a maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven, servlets

Consider the following situation: I have a maven project `base` that contains a Servlet 3.0 comaptible web application that is configured through a `web.xml` file.
This project is being packaged as a WAR archive and published on a Tomcat 7.0 server.

I am now planning to develop an optional extension for this project. This is a maven project called `addon`. `base` should include `addon` as a dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.example.addon</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

`addon` should also provide servlets/filters/context listeners as per the servlet 3.0 specifications.

What are best practices to achieve this. Can `addon` maintain a `web.xml` itself or are changes in `base` necessary for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid `base` need to maintain it's own `web.xml` based on my experience using JSF, where I need to setup my application's `web.xml` to register JSF listener and servlet.